# What's the $\left \| \text{Jacobian matrix} \right \|$ of $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$?

Tags: calculus, jacobian

> Given is $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$
>
> Determine $\left\| J \right\|_{X,Y}$

I'm not sure if I did it correctly?

So we first derivate to $x$: $f(x,y)' = \frac{1}{y}$

Now derivate to $y$: $f(x,y)' = -\frac{x}{y^2}$

And now we somehow build the Jacobian matrix with these.. but how?

It should be $J= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{y} & -\frac{x}{y^2} 
\end{pmatrix}$

If this is correct, then $\left\| J \right\|$ should be $\sqrt{({\frac{1}{y})^2}+(-\frac{x}{y^2})^2}$ ?

Comment: "... but how?": you look up the definition of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: @OpenBall I did. But I'm not sure if I did it all correctly.

Comment: The Jacobi Matrix looks good

Comment: I am not sure if $||J||$ is correct, I get 0

Comment: It is correct. ${}$

Comment: @copper.hat $||J||$ defined as $\sqrt{det(J^{T}*J)}$, isn't it?

Comment: Since you’re talking about a single function of two variables, i.e. a map defined on a subset of $\Bbb R^2$, into $\Bbb R^1$, you expect a two-by-one (or is it one-by-two?) jacobian matrix.

Comment: @Lubin it is $1 \times 2$ matrix

Comment: @Chiray: No. Unfortunately the term Jacobian is used for $Df(x)$ as well as the Jacobian that arises in a change of variables formula.

Comment: @Lubin so if you go from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ you expect a $m \times n$ Jacobi Matrix

Comment: @copper.hat Is my Jacobian matrix a $(1 \times 2)$ matrix or what is it?And is the ||J|| correct too?

Comment: @cnmesr: Yes. ${}{}$